# How to know the voltages between inductors?

Tags: voltage, pcb, circuit-analysis, inductor

I've got a schematic as below, but I don't know what voltage is a output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6bm2d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It depends. In steady-state, assuming no external changing magnetic fields, this would simply be a voltage divider across the resistance of the material making the wires and inductors.

Comment: @hexafraction Thanks for advice, but I'm not familiar with this about background. Would you please let me know by English? does it out 1.8?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I believe that I've explained the problem fully using the English language already.

Comment: @hexafraction I'm meaning please let me know more easily..

Comment: @hexafraction Does output out 1.8V or 2.85?

Comment: It's neither 1.8 nor 2.85 volts. It depends on the properties of the inductors, as I mentioned in my initial comment. They form a voltage divider in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideal inductors have zero voltage drop across them. That means that that connection will probably pull the 1.8v supply up to 2.85v, and the output voltage will be 2.85v.

In other words, what this means is that there is no answer to this question given the information shown, it is the non-idealities of the components shown that will supply the answer. What will happen to power supplies shorted together? Do the inductors have sufficient internal resistance not to short the supplies together? if so, what is the value of that resistance?

Comment: No, I'm not sure. Which part of the word 'probably' don't you understand?

Comment: To rephrase (since I worded that terribly the first time), what makes that case (2.85 pulling up the 1.8 supply) the most likely?